# Was Wedge Antilles present at the climax of Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Due to Rogue One being set close in time to Episode IV,

> we see the original Red Five die at the battle of Scarif leaving the call sign available for Luke.

But, was Wedge Antilles part of Red Squadron at this point? If so, would he logically have taken part in the battle? We know there are survivors such as Red and Gold leader.

I can understand the actor not wanting to reprise his role, but was the character technically present?

Comment: David Ankrum, Wedge's original voice actor, [certainly was](https://twitter.com/DavidAnkrum1/status/809516075578757121); not sure about the character though

Comment: TIL he was played by two different people, and voiced by a third!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think Wedge is involved in the battle.

Reason for saying so was that in ANH, Wedge (Red 2) can be heard saying "look at the size of that thing", suggesting that being the first time he saw the Death Star.

[EDIT] Confirmed by Pablo Hidalgo: https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/820744041868324864

Image source: http://www.starwarsnewsnet.com/2017/01/lucasfilm-staff-explain-where-wedge-was-during-star-wars-rogue-one.html

[image]

Comment: I will keep the question open a bit longer just in case but i'm inclined to mark this as the answer, purely because it does provide the nearest in-universe evidence to support an answer to my question.

Comment: Pablo Hidalgo just confirmed what I thought: https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/820744041868324864

Comment: Very well spotted! Want to update your answer with the source confirming?

Comment: Added the extra info.

Answer (score 11):

### No, Wedge was not involved at Scarif

It's not known if he was part of Red Squadron yet, but [Pablo Hidalgo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo), a continuity and story development executive with the Lucasfilm Story Group, confirmed [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/819426039155654656) that he wasn't involved in the battle:

[image]

> **@ShannonGCarter** Were Wedge, Biggs, John D, Porkins, Theron Nett, Tiree and Pops at Scarif in Rogue One?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Wedge definitely wasn't. Biggs, doubtful. The rest, probably, in that we didn't reassign their call numbers.

### He may have been on Yavin

As I mentioned in a comment on the question, David Ankrum, the original voice actor for Wedge<sup>1</sup> had a brief voice cameo, as revealed in [an interview](http://www.sfchronicle.com/movies/article/Sage-of-sound-at-Skywalker-26-years-in-fantasy-10793472.php) with sound designer Matthew Wood:

> Following his tendency to use the same handful of actors for the vocal roles, Wood has brought original 1977 "Star Wars" actors on board to use their voices for "Rogue One," such as Angus MacInnes and David Ankrum, who played Gold Leader and Red Two in "A New Hope."

Ankrum himself revealed [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/DavidAnkrum1/status/811335715846062081) that he could be heard over the public address system at Yavin base:

[image]

> **@RenderedAddison** I am listening for your voice. What scene is it in?
>
> **@DavidAnkrum1** PA Announcer on Yavin. Redirecting the pilots to Scarif!

Whether or not Ankrum's voice is meant to be Wedge is, as far as I know, unknown; Ankrum himself claims as much in [his Twitter biography](https://twitter.com/DavidAnkrum1), but it hasn't been confirmed by more official sources as far as I know.

---

<sup>1</sup> Random Star Wars trivia time: Wedge was portrayed in body by two actors: Colin Higgins (in the briefing scene) and Denis Lawson (in the Death Star battle itself), but both actors' lines were overdubbed by David Ankrum

Answer (score 6):

Wedge was not in the battle but I assume he would have been part of the rebel alliance at that time. He was just elsewhere.

The Captain Antilles they page in the hanger was likely the Captain Antilles 3PO refers to in A New Hope. He was 3PO's master and Captain of the Tantive IV.

Comment: Indeed, he had already defected from the empire to the alliance a few years prior to rogue one. Also, welcome to the site!

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, yes.  The IMDB trivia page for the movie says "A call for a Captain Antilles can be heard as the rebels prepare for their assault on Scariff."

http://m.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/trivia

Comment: There are several Captains Antilles; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Raymus_Antilles/Legends